# Android Urban Airship migrating from 5.1 to 6.2

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

We have a class that extends Action, in the perform method, and we do a switch on the actionName. In version 6.2, the actionName variable is no longer a part of the method signature. How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its part of the action metadata now:

```
String actionName = arguments.getMetadata()
                             .getString(ActionArguments.REGISTRY_ACTION_NAME_METADATA);
```

http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/android-migration.html#actions